# Haskell streaming - how to merge original stream with result stream

Tags: haskell, streaming, haskell-streaming

Using [Haskell-streaming](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming), I can easily group a stream and take sum on each group.

```
>>> S.print $ mapped S.toList $ S.groupBy (\ x y -> x*y>0) $ each [-1,-2,3,4,5,-6]
[-1,-2]
[3,4,5]
[-6]

>>> S.print $S.map sum $ mapped S.toList $ S.groupBy (\ x y -> x*y>0) $ each [-1,-2,3,4,5,-6]
-3
12
-6
```

How to have a function `myfn` that generates a stream that is a merge of the two above in an order sensitive way? I.e. I wish to have a result stream of

```
>>> myfn $ each [-1,-2,3,4,5,-6]
-1:> -2:> -3:> 3:> 4:> 5:> 12:> -6:> -6:> ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involves making the function argument of `mapped` both accumulate the list *and* calculate the sum, in one pass.

That can be done with [`store`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:store) I think, but I find the streaming sinks from [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) easier to use. Their `Applicative` instance lets us build composite `Fold`s from simpler ones:

```
foo :: Monad m 
    => (Int -> Int -> Bool) 
    -> Stream (Of Int) m ()
    -> Stream (Of Int) m ()
foo p = 
      flip S.for (\(xs,total) -> S.each xs *> S.yield total)
    . mapped (L.purely S.fold $ (,) <$> L.list <*> L.sum)
    . S.groupBy p
```

Where [`L.purely`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.6/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:purely), [`L.list`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.6/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:list) and [`L.sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.6/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:sum) are from "foldl".

The finishing touch is taking each pair `([Int],Int)` coming out of `mapped` and replacing it with a substream using [`for`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:for).

Putting it to work:

```
*Main> S.print $ foo (\x y -> x*y>0) $ S.each [-1,-2,3,4,5,-6]
```

---

**Edit:** Come to think of it, the previous solution is flawed. We are only interested in a *streamed* result, yet we accumulate each individual group in memory using `S.toList` or `L.list` before sending it downstream. But what if one group happens to be bigger than the available memory in the machine?

Here's a solution that streams perfectly and is indifferent to the size of each group:

```
foo :: Monad m 
    => (Int -> Int -> Bool) 
    -> Stream (Of Int) m ()
    -> Stream (Of Int) m ()
foo p = 
      concats
    . S.maps (S.store (\s -> do (total :> r) <- L.purely S.fold L.sum s
                                S.yield total
                                return r))
    . S.groupBy p
```

What has changed? First, we use [`maps`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:maps) instead of [`mapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:mapped), because now we want to transform the subgroup streams, instead of returning a result in the base monad.

For each subgroup stream, we use [`store`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:store) to perform a summing fold without destroying the stream. Then we take the result of the fold and append it back to the stream, while also taking care of preserving the original return value as required by `maps`.

The only step left is to rejoin the subgroups using [`concats`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming.html#v:concats).